# OSError: cannot open resource - File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py"

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, raspberry-pi

I have a python script that is supposed to write raspberry´s sensor data on a small Display. It calls ImageFont.py for Fonts which returns the error message that follows and that relates to line 145:

```
143 if isPath(font):
144     self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding,
145                              layout_engine=layout_engine)                              


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/uhr.py", line 1, in <module>
    from display import anzeige
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 276, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/display.py", line 15, in <module>
    font = ImageFont.truetype("/home/pi/fonts/BBrick.ttf", 18)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 280, in truetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 145, in __init__
layout_engine=layout_engine)
```

OSError: cannot open resource

I am a bit lost with this one as 144-145 come from an imported library which should work. I looked for solutions on the same OSError but what I found had other issues. Could anybody explain the error and maybe knows a fix?

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Did you ask over on the issue tracker for that library?

Comment: Thank you, @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, I was not aware of that. When I search for "issue trackers ImageFont", I get results like [link](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html) or "bugs.python.org" but I don´t think that is what you are mean, right? At least they don´t provide help. I am not familiar with issues tracker so far but would welcome a hint.

Comment: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ - I guess the original PIL till use mailing lists instead of modern issue trackers.